# RStudio Viewer Error: "session/viewhtml...." not found

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently installed a daily build version of R Studio, 1.4.671. Since that installation, anything that runs in the viewer (e.g. `gt` or `lavaanPlot`) gives me an error like this:

`/session/viewhtml528813ce72d/index.html?viewer_pane=1&capabilities=1&host=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A27742 not found`

I have fully uninstalled 1.4.671, restarted my computer, and reinstalled the version that worked this morning, 1.3.1056. Not sure

This is becoming quite a problem because I am not able to easily see any model coefficients that I am currently working on (in a neat way, they are messy in the console).

I have also reset RStudio's state following https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-s-State and removed my .Renviron file.

Update: if the error shows but I choose to export as HTML, the HTML file works.
Update2: both running Shiny and knitting an RMarkdown document to HTML works. It's just displaying something inside RStudio's viewer that is causing issues.

[image: image|690x324]

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gt_0.2.1           patchwork_1.0.0    waffle_1.0.1      
 [4] plotly_4.9.2.1     ggstance_0.3.4     ggridges_0.5.2    
 [7] foreign_0.8-78     gghighlight_0.3.0  gridExtra_2.3     
[10] readxl_1.3.1       emmeans_1.4.7      broom_0.5.6       
[13] fastDummies_1.6.1  modelsummary_0.5.0 tables_0.9.3      
[16] gtsummary_1.3.2    janitor_2.0.1      haven_2.3.1       
[19] forcats_0.5.0      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_1.0.0       
[22] purrr_0.3.4        readr_1.3.1        tidyr_1.1.0       
[25] tibble_3.0.1       ggplot2_3.3.1      tidyverse_1.3.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-147       fs_1.4.1           lubridate_1.7.8   
 [4] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 httr_1.4.1         tools_4.0.0       
 [7] backports_1.1.7    DT_0.13            R6_2.4.1          
[10] DBI_1.1.0          lazyeval_0.2.2     colorspace_1.4-1  
[13] withr_2.2.0        tidyselect_1.1.0   extrafontdb_1.0   
[16] curl_4.3           compiler_4.0.0     cli_2.0.2         
[19] rvest_0.3.5        xml2_1.3.2         sandwich_2.5-1    
[22] labeling_0.3       sass_0.2.0         scales_1.1.1      
[25] checkmate_2.0.0    mvtnorm_1.1-0      commonmark_1.7    
[28] digest_0.6.25      rmarkdown_2.2      pkgconfig_2.0.3   
[31] htmltools_0.5.0    extrafont_0.17     dbplyr_1.4.4      
[34] htmlwidgets_1.5.1  rlang_0.4.6        rstudioapi_0.11   
[37] farver_2.0.3       generics_0.0.2     zoo_1.8-8         
[40] jsonlite_1.6.1     magrittr_1.5       Matrix_1.2-18     
[43] Rcpp_1.0.4.6       munsell_0.5.0      fansi_0.4.1       
[46] lifecycle_0.2.0    stringi_1.4.6      multcomp_1.4-13   
[49] yaml_2.2.1         snakecase_0.11.0   MASS_7.3-51.5     
[52] plyr_1.8.6         grid_4.0.0         blob_1.2.1        
[55] crayon_1.3.4       lattice_0.20-41    splines_4.0.0     
[58] hms_0.5.3          knitr_1.28         pillar_1.4.4      
[61] estimability_1.3   codetools_0.2-16   reprex_0.3.0      
[64] glue_1.4.1         packrat_0.5.0      evaluate_0.14     
[67] data.table_1.12.8  modelr_0.1.8       vctrs_0.3.0       
[70] Rttf2pt1_1.3.8     cellranger_1.1.0   gtable_0.3.0      
[73] assertthat_0.2.1   xfun_0.14          xtable_1.8-4      
[76] coda_0.19-3        survival_3.1-12    viridisLite_0.3.0 
[79] TH.data_1.0-10     ellipsis_0.3.1    
>
```